# Unable to see data packets sent to another device on the same network by the WiFi router using Wireshark's promiscuous mode

Tags: router, wireshark, wireless, packet-capture

This is my set up:

Access point: 
Acer router WiFi network. It is not connected to internet or something. Just plugged in the power and that's it.

Client(s):
My computer.
My phone.

Connect the phone and computer to the Acer router WiFi network and then start Wireshark in Promiscuous mode for the wireless interface on my computer.

What I expected to see:
Messages that are sent to the computer from the Acer router and also messages which sent by the Acer router to the phone (since I am in Promiscuous mode).

These were my settings:

[image]

An ip address was assigned by the router to my computer and phone:

[image]

[image]

Sniffing begins – mostly packets between router and computer.

[image]

Not sure why only that ARP packet is visible via the promiscuous mode sniffing. This is the only place where I can see something about the phone. I was expecting to see all packets that are sent from the router to the phone since I am using promiscuous mode.

I expected to see the same volume of message flow from the router to the phone as I saw between router and computer. 
But that didn’t happen. I am not sure if this is because one device was a Linux based computer and the other an Android based phone.

Are my expectations wrong? Or is my set up wrong? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Is your network secured by WPA2, or is it open?

Comment: It is just a network I created for fun. So it is completely open. No security whatsoever.

Comment: ok. In case of WPA2 you would have needed to capture also the handshake between the AP and the respective client in order to be able to decode their communication. But in case of an open Wifi network, obviously this is no factor.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first screenshot, it appears that you are not capturing in [Monitor Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode).

You will need to put your wireless card into monitor mode to see data frames being exchanged by other stations.

Note that your wireless card and device driver will need to support this.  See this [tutorial](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatible_cards) for more information about driver compatibility with monitor mode.